# How to convert a dataframe to tidy form (unpivot)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `df = pd.read_excel('...')`:

```
Date     Id V1  V2  V3
2020-1-1  1 10 100 NaN
2020-1-1  2 20 120  23
2020-1-1  3 11 101 NaN
```

I need to transform it to

```
Date      Name Value
2020-1-1  1_V1    10
2020-1-1  1_V2   100
2020-1-1  2_V1    20
2020-1-1  2_V2   120
2020-1-1  2_V3    23
2020-1-1  3_V1    11
2020-1-1  3_V2   101
```

The `'Name'` column is a concatenation of `Id` and column names of `V1`, `V2`, `V3`, etc. The `NaN` values are ignored.

How to implement it using dataframe features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `melt`

```
s = df.melt(['Date','Id']).dropna()
s['name'] = s.pop('variable') +'_'+ s.pop('Id').astype(str)
s
       Date  value  name
0  2020-1-1   10.0  V1_1
1  2020-1-1   20.0  V1_2
2  2020-1-1   11.0  V1_3
3  2020-1-1  100.0  V2_1
4  2020-1-1  120.0  V2_2
5  2020-1-1  101.0  V2_3
7  2020-1-1   23.0  V3_2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
df1 = df.melt(['Date','Id']).dropna()
df1 = df1.assign(Name=df1.Id.astype(str) + '_' + df1.variable)
df1[['Date','Name','value']]
```

Output

```
       Date  Name  value
0  2020-1-1  1_V1   10.0
1  2020-1-1  2_V1   20.0
2  2020-1-1  3_V1   11.0
3  2020-1-1  1_V2  100.0
4  2020-1-1  2_V2  120.0
5  2020-1-1  3_V2  101.0
7  2020-1-1  2_V3   23.0
```